# PHP in_array seeing if there is a better way to do this

Tags: php, arrays

A lot of my websites share the same assets and credit cards are one of them. So I created a sprite containing all of the credit card icons.

In my info file I have a variable liks this:

```
$credit_cards = array("visa", "mastercard", "discover", "amex");
```

and then  in the Footer where I am displaying the icons, I have something like this:

```
<?php
if (in_array("visa", $credit_cards)) {
    echo "<span class='card-visa'></span>";
}
if (in_array("mastercard", $credit_cards)) {
    echo "<span class='card-mastercard'></span>";
}
if (in_array("discover", $credit_cards)) {
    echo "<span class='card-discover'></span>";
}
if (in_array("amex", $credit_cards)) {
    echo "<span class='card-amex'></span>";
}
?>
```

So on my starting template, all I have to do is edit the info file and choose which credit cards I want to be shown.  If in the future the client wants to add or remove a card that they don't accept anymore, I just take it out of the array.

You might think this is crazy, but there's more to it then just the 4 major credit cards. This is for the automotive industry and there are a lot of other cards such as wright, goodyear, carcare, GE, shell, etc. I just pasted a snippet of the 4 major ones.

Is there a better way to do this? I know the solution above is really messy and I feel like there has to be a cleaner solution out there.. I just need some suggestions on what you think is best.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _better_? If you mean _faster_ than possibly not, `in_array` is quite fast.

Comment: I guess less code was what I was going for. deceze's solution works great. thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach ($credit_cards as $card) {
    echo "<span class='card-$card'></span>";
}
```

This is where consistent naming schemes pay off.

Comment: Wow it was that simple. I appreciate it, thank you. I was over-thinking it.

Comment: For cases like this: start with *reduction*. If two things are always identical in your code, replace them with a variable. The solution should then become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "better", but you can at least factor out shared code:

```
<?php
function print_card($card) {
    if (in_array($card, $GLOBALS['credit_cards'])) {
        echo "<span class='card-$card'></span>";
    }
}

print_card('visa');
print_card('mastercard');
print_card('discover');
print_card('amex');
?>
```